# What is the meaning of ~에를 and how is it different from just ~에?

Tags: grammar, particle

In the following sentence:

> 오늘은 날씨가 너무 더워서 **밖에를** 못 나가겠어요.

According to my dictionary, it seems to mean the location to which the verb does an action. But then what it the difference from just using 에? I don’t understand why the sentence above uses 를 with the verb 나가다, which seems strange.

Comment: [를](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=85764) emphasizes that part.

Comment: from sense 10 of link from @Klmo: Reference  주로 조사 ‘에', '으로’, 연결 어미 ‘-아', '-게', '-지', '-고’, 받침 없는 일부 부사 뒤에 붙여 쓴다.

Answer (score -1):

It should look strange if you're studying Korean by the book. The correct representation of the above sentence should be "오늘은 날씨가 너무 더워서 밖을 못 나가겠어요" or "오늘은 날씨가 너무 더워서 밖에 못나가겠어요".

However, sometimes people use the term "밖에" in the place of "밖". I believe that it's because people use "밖" with "-에" so often that it became natural to use "밖에" as a whole.

This happens only in casual spoken conversations and usually only for relative location terms. "밖에를", "안에를", "위에를" are often heard but "학교에를", "회사에를", "고향에를" are not.

Comment: This is wrong. Klmo and user17915 left a good answer in the comments section. Consider this sentence: "더워서 바깥에를 나갔어요"